# How to remove group tags (<g>) from svg content while setting svg content through setSvgString in svg editor?

Tags: svg

For this issue, I have traced execution of setting svg content in svgcanvas.js file of svg editor, but no luck. I have even tried to remove g tags in "text2xml" call, but no luck.

please help me out...

Following code i have tried, here i have uploaded svg file and read that file through reader:

```
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var xmlString=e.target.result;
    xmlDoc = $jq.parseXML(xmlString);
    var xmlElements=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    var reXmlElements=new Array();
    var j=0;
    for (var i=0; i<xmlElements.length; i++) {
        if(xmlElements[i].nodeName=="g") {
            //xmlElements[i].remove();
            reXmlElements[j]=xmlElements[i].children[0];
            j++;
        } else {
            //reXmlElements[j]=xmlElements[i];
        }
    }
    xmlDoc.documentElement.children=reXmlElements;
    console.log(xmlDoc.documentElement.children);
    console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc));

    svgCanvas.setSvgString(e.target.result);
```

Comment: by reading xml tag and tried to g tag but while removing g tag it removes its child also.

Comment: I have given tried code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have solved this issue by doing following stuff:

```
svgCanvas.setSvgString(e.target.result);
                    svgEditor.changeZoom({value: (100*zoomlevel)});
                    //setSvgConfiguration(imprintWidth[side], imprintHeight[side], imprintLeft[side], imprintTop[side]);
                    document.querySelector("#svgcontent").setAttribute("overflow","hidden");
                    maxWidth=document.querySelector("#svgcontent").getAttribute("width");
                    maxHeight=document.querySelector("#svgcontent").getAttribute("height");

                    if($jq("#svgcontent g").length > 0 && $jq("#svgcontent g").children().length > 0) {
                        var allElements = $jq("#svgcontent g").children();
                        $jq("#svgcontent g:first").html("");
                        for(var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
                            var element = allElements[i];
                            if(element.tagName == "g") {
                                for(var j=0;j<element.children.length;j++) {
                                    $jq("#svgcontent g:first").append(element.children[j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        allElements = $jq("#svgcontent g").children();
```